# Python ctypes.Structure "c_void_p" type converted to "long"

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

So I've got a simple ctypes Structure with a c_void_p field defined, but when I try to get its type(), I get 'long'. The strange part is that if the variable is not defined in the _ fields _, the type() comes back with c_void_p.

For example:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import *

class myClass(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_void_p)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ctypes.cast(LPSTR("ABC"), LPVOID)
        self.y = ctypes.cast(LPSTR("ABC"), LPVOID)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = myClass()
    print inst.x, getattr(inst,"x"), type(inst.x)
    print inst.y, getattr(inst,"y"), type(inst.y)
```

This outputs the following:

```
38561064 38561064 <type 'long'>
c_void_p(38561064L) c_void_p(38561064L) <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
```

So basically, since the variable "x" is part of the _ fields _, it gets converted into a "long", but "y" does not.

My question is, is it possible to get "x" as a c_void_p type back??

I know some of you will say, just do c_void_p(inst.x). By doing this you lose some information such as the contents of "_objects" which contains the object the pointer points to. For the example above, inst.y._objects is "ABC" but inst.x._objects does not exist as inst.x is a long, and c_void_p(inst.x) does not bring back that information

Any thoughts??

Comment: `x` is a C field. It's not stored in the instance dict like `y`. It's accessed via the `myClass.x` data descriptor, which automatically converts types with a native Python `value`, including simple ctypes and `c_char` and `c_wchar` arrays -- except not subclasses of simple types. The same behavior applies to accessing unions and arrays, dereferencing non-simple pointers, and setting these types as the `restype` of a function.

Comment: If you need reference support for a pointer field, use a non-simple pointer or a subclass of a simple pointer. Note that this uses `_b_base_` to reference the struct instance, not  `_objects`, because the object created when accessing the field doesn't own the memory (i.e. the 4 or 8 bytes that holds the address). It references the memory at the field offset of the struct.